# SQL Server compare datetime fields

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a datetime field in my table that I need to use in a where clause.
The fieldname is DatumAanname
In my dataviewgrid it shows for example "16/12/2014 15:57:04"

I looked at the page from microsoft with all the datetime options for a convert, but this format does not seems to be on that page.
The closest format I can see there is "16 12 2014 15:57:04" which should be 113

I tried a query like this

```
SELECT o.DatumAanname,
    (convert(DATETIME, '16 dec 2014 15:57:04:000', 113)),
    (convert(DATETIME, '16 dec 2014 15:57:04', 113)),
    (convert(DATETIME, o.DatumAanname, 113))
FROM vwOpdracht o
```

this returns 4 fields which all look exact the same

but when I do

```
where (convert(datetime, o.DatumAanname, 113)) = (convert(datetime, '16 dec 2014 15:57:04:000', 113))
```

it returns 0 records

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: whether `o.DatumAanname` has `16 dec 2014 15:57:04` date in it

Comment: 113 is `dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm` - `mmm` part is necessarily

Comment: As I said in my question, the datagridview shows a record with value "16/12/2014 15:57:04" so YES that value is in there. Also in my question I said that my query shows 4 columns with exactly the same value, so how would it be possible for this value not to be in there N

Comment: I tried with the :mmm included, still does not works

Comment: Just edited my question to include the :mmm part

Comment: @GuidoG Calm down. I noticed and I removed my comment. Is the `datagridview` something in your application or is it an actual `VIEW` in SQL Server which you call and returns this data?

Comment: @Radu, sorry about that but you where the second person with that comment, I also removed my comment

Comment: you might be running into accuracy issues, datetime is only accurate to 0.003 sec and the converts might be coming out slightly different.

Comment: I run my query in sql server managment studio (thanks Radu for the idea) and it turns out there is a value in the mmm part which is not shown by the datagridview. What I think is strange is that when I convert it using Convert(datetime, DatumAanname,113) the milliseconds are cleared. Anyway, the grid is bound to a datatable, can I get the value including the milliseconds from the datatable or from the datagridview or is there another solutions for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates have no formats, they are native types with their own binary storage. Formats and conversions apply only when converting from/to string and they frequently cause problems if incompatible collations and cultures are used.

The best way to avoid problems is simply to remove strings entirely: use date-typed columns in the table and query using parameterized queries. Actually, if the date is stored as text in the table there is *no* generic and fault-proof way to acoid problems.

Pass strongly typed values instead of strings (eg DateTime in C#, date, datetime,datetime2 in T-SQL). For example:

```
where o.DatumAanname= @dateParam
```

will return matching entries if the values match.

If passing date parameters isn't possible, you should *only* use [the unambiguous ISO8691 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx#ISO8601Format), eg:

```
where o.DatumAanname = '2014-12-16T15:57:04'
```

If you want to pass date-only values you can use the unseparated format which is also unambiguous

```
where o.DatumAanname = '20141216'
```

One thing to note is that date values must match exactly, down to the millisecond. Typically dates are used in range queries where this isn't an issue. In equality queries though, this can be a problem.

You can avoid this by using `datetime2(0)` as the field type, which ensures that milliseconds aren't stored at all.

Another option is to use a range instead of an equality query, eg:

```
where o.DatumAanname between '2014-12-16T15:57:04' and '2014-12-16T15:57:04.999'
```

or

```
where o.DatumAanname between '2014-12-16T15:57:00' and '2014-12-16T15:57:59'
```

if you want minute-level precision

Comment: Unfortunate the database is created using datetime in stead of datetime2. I tried casting the field to datetime2 but it still contains the milliseconds.

Comment: The datetime2 type accepts a precision argument, just like `numeric`, to specify the millisecond precision. `datetime2(0)` contains no milliseconds. You should be careful though because conversions or applying any sort of function on a field prevent the optimizer from using indexes. The optimizer has special handling for dates, but you should check the execution plan to ensure you don't end up with a full table scan. Perhaps you should modify your query to a range query between the second you want and the next (or whatever precision level you want)